# How to load linked page before leaving current page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've got a very wide question and I'm sure there is no short answer for it but maybe someone of you can lead me in the right direction.

I wonder how to load a web page when you click on a link before leaving the current page; thus causing no white flicker between this page and the next page. I know gmail uses it, you see that "loading" thingy at the top before leaving the current page. I've also got an example of what i want to accomplish on this site: http://www.barrelny.com/ , you see a loading icon in the middle of this page before redirecting.

I didn't find much on google regarding this.
I don't really know what language to use to do this, but I know quite a bit of most of them.
Help much appreciated.

Comment: You should read into AJAX

Comment: HTML5 has very nice unimplemented (of course) specs for this: [link prefetching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Link_prefetching_FAQ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single-site websites or also gmail make use of AJAX. [jQuery, for instance, has a lot of AJAX features and a really good api](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

With AJAX you can load html without having to reload the website.

Comment: I have used some Ajax scripts before to load php and mysql into html sites, and I can see how that could work, but I thought they used some other method due to the URL changing, at least Barrel which I linked changes the URL, gmail just uses hash symbols while redirecting so that's understandable. But I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You want to build a Single Page Application. With a Single Page Application you only have on html page, and you load your data dynamically through AJAX.

This is most easiest made with javascript frameworks such as Ember, Angular or Backbone. 
See http://angularjs.org/, http://backbonejs.org/ and http://emberjs.com/

Secondly you might want to read into AJAX, and how you can use that with your php / .net server.

And last but not least google 'Single Page Application'and read as much as you can find.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine these sites load the requested page dynamically via an ajax request which, when complete, replaces the page content, changes the address and pushes the old page location to history.

Perhaps something similar to this old post of Chris Coyier's:

http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-page-replacing-content/